# pop component in android without xml layout

Tags: android

I need to create popup window or overlay in android without using layouts,like in ios,
can anyone help me in solving this,if there is any library for creating popups or overlay in android let me know?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Comment: :i need to create android component for Popping up model from all activities?